# Can someone enlighten me on why the loss function in this code doesn't get it right?

Tags: python, neural-network, loss-function

So this code builds neural networks that have for objective to classify correctly digits on the MNIST dataset.

The technique used for the network to learn is not back propagation, instead it uses (or try to use at least) a technique called neuroevolution that is based on the Darwin principle of Evolution, to build a population of neural networks, evaluate them, and take the best of them to produce a new generation of neural networks etc.

In this code, I create a population of 10 neural networks that are evaluated on a cross-entropy loss function.
I keep the 5 best of them for the next generation, and replace the 5 others, with "child" networks created from the 5 already kept.

My problem is that, I don't see the same networks (the ones that are kept) keeping the same loss value from a generation to another.

e.g if the 5 best networks are evaluated, it displays a certain loss value for each of them, then they are kept for the next generation, and all the population is reevaluated. But there I can't find the same  loss values as previously.
As the population is presented in a list object, and kept in the same order, if the 5 freshly created other "child" networks, were better, then they should replace the values of the 5 previously kept networks, but it shows, that "child" networks tend often to have worst values, and still apparently the loss values calculated for the kept networks vary from one generation to another.

In short sentence: the loss value from one generation to another for the SAME networks objects is not the same, while taking exactly the same data, and same parameters.

If someone has time to look at it and has an insight on what is wrong in the code. It is probably a code issue somewhere, in the calculation of the loss, but I can't figure it out.

PS: I also saw and there is some code displaying it, that the calculation of the loss value for a particular network varies very slightly (decimals), from one calculation to another, and that is something that I already don't understand, but it still can't explain the big differences in loss value calculation from one generation to another.

So here is the three modules of my code:

First module:

```
"""
Utility used by the Network class to actually train.
Based on:
    https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py
"""
#from keras.datasets import cifar10

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
import numpy as np





def get_mnist():
    """Get MNIST dataset through scikit-learn and pre-process data to make it usable by our classifiers"""

    mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')

    #X as images - array (70000, 784) corresponding respectively to the number of examples and the number of pixels per image
    #y as labels  - array (70000,) corresponding to the number of examples, each value is a digit from 0 to 9
    X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]

    #Normalize pixels of images
    X = X / 255


    digits = 10
    examples = y.shape[0]

    # Reshape y as array (1, 70000)
    y = y.reshape(1, examples)

    """Create a label array of shape (10, 70000) and replace each digit value from 0 to 9 by value of 1.
        Rest of the array composed of zeros.
    Allow us to design it the same way as our networks's output array will be, with the maximum value corresponding to what the digit is."""
    Y_new = np.eye(digits)[y.astype('int32')]
    Y_new = Y_new.T.reshape(digits, examples)

    m = 60000
    m_test = X.shape[0] - m

    #Get images for train set and test set, transposing in array of shape (784, 60000) and (784, 10000)
    X_train, X_test = X[:m].T, X[m:].T

    #Get labels for train set and test set
    Y_train, Y_test = Y_new[:,:m], Y_new[:,m:]

    #Shuffle train set to randomize it as it is organized from digits 0 to 9
    shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(m)
    X_train, Y_train = X_train[:, shuffle_index], Y_train[:, shuffle_index]


    return (X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test)


def sigmoid(z):
    #sigmoid activation function
    s = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
    return s


def compute_multiclass_loss(Y, Y_hat):
    """Fitness function: Categorical cross-entropy cost function, used in the case of multi-class outputs."""
    L_sum = np.sum(np.multiply(Y, np.log(10**(-15)+Y_hat)))
    m = Y.shape[1]
    L = -(1/m) * L_sum

    return L

def compute_accuracy(Y, Y_hat):
    """Fitness function: a different way to compute cost function, with accuracy.
    Tested, seems to work but the formula has to be verified as it may contain potential approximations"""

    correct = 0
    uncorrect = 0
    argmax_Y = np.argmax(Y, axis=0)
    argmax_Y_hat = np.argmax(Y_hat, axis=0)
    for i in range(60000):
        if argmax_Y[i] == argmax_Y_hat[i]:
            correct += 1
        else:
            uncorrect += 1

    accuracy = correct / (correct + uncorrect)

    return accuracy




def neural_network_evaluator(input_layer_to_hidden_layer, hidden_layer_to_output_layer, b1, b2):
    """Function used to: 1/ forwardpropagate the input in a particular neural network
    2/ Generate outputs
    3/ Determine the cost of fitness function for this network"""

    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = get_mnist()

    #Feedforward for training neural network on training set
    Z1 = np.matmul(input_layer_to_hidden_layer,X_train) + b1
    A1 = sigmoid(Z1)
    Z2 = np.matmul(hidden_layer_to_output_layer,A1) + b2
    A2 = np.exp(Z2) / np.sum(np.exp(Z2), axis=0)

    cost = compute_multiclass_loss(Y_train, A2)



    return cost
```

Second module:

```
"""
Class that holds a genetic algorithm for evolving a network.
Credit:
    A lot of those code was originally inspired by:
    http://lethain.com/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/
"""
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
import numpy as np
import random
import logging
from train_Neuroevolution_ameliored import neural_network_evaluator
from train_Neuroevolution_ameliored import get_mnist

class Optimizer():
    """Class that implements genetic algorithm for MLP optimization.
        Evolving process.
        Cross-over and mutation processes.

        Also used as neural network creator class triggered AFTER evolution process, and used for multiple purposes.
        Neural network object creator.
        Populations creator for both pre and post evolution.
        Average fitness of populations.
        Cost value compiler.
        ..."""

    def __init__(self, retain=0.5, random_select=0.0, mutation_rate=0.5):
        """Create an optimizer.
        Args:
            retain (float): Percentage of population to retain after
                each generation
            random_select (float): Probability of a rejected network
                remaining in the population
            mutation_rate (float): Probability a network will be
                randomly mutated
            ...

        Initialize our network parameters, for network population after first evolution.
        """

        self.mutation_rate = mutation_rate
        self.random_select = random_select
        self.retain = retain
        self.accuracy = 0.
        self.network = []
        self.b1 = 0
        self.b1_lines = 64
        self.b2 = 0
        self.b2_lines = 10
        self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer = 0
        self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer_shape_lines = 64
        self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer_shape_columns = 784
        self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer = 0
        self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer_shape_lines = 10
        self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer_shape_columns = 64





    def create_neural_network(self, dataset):
        """ Randomly set parameters for a neural network object with a fixed structure.
            Structure is: - one input layer with 784 inputs corresponding to each pixel of the MNIST dataset
                            - one hidden layer with 64 neurons (arbitrary value)
                            - one output layer with 10 neurons determining each of the 10 digits probability"""

        #We can ignore Cifar10 as it is not build for it for the moment
        """if dataset == 'cifar10':
            nb_classes, batch_size, input_shape, x_train, \
                x_test, y_train, y_test = get_cifar10()"""


        if dataset == 'mnist':
            X_train = get_mnist() [0]

        n_x = X_train.shape[0]
        n_h = 64

        self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer = np.random.randn(n_h, n_x) #Weights from input to hidden layer
        self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer_shape_lines = self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer.shape[0] #Used for weights mutation
        self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer_shape_columns = self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer.shape[1] #Used for weights mutation
        self.b1 = np.zeros((n_h, 1)) #Biases for hidden layer
        self.b1_lines = self.b1.shape[0] #Used for biases mutation

        self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer = np.random.randn(10, n_h) #Weights from hidden to output layer
        self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer_shape_lines = self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer.shape[0] #Used for weights mutation
        self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer_shape_columns = self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer.shape[1] #Used for weights mutation
        self.b2 = np.zeros((10, 1)) #Biases for output layer
        self.b2_lines = self.b2.shape[0] #Used for biases mutation

        self.network = [[self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer], [self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer], [self.b1], [self.b2]] #Network structure with in


    def fitness(self, network):
        """Return accuracy, which is our fitness function value after the first evolution."""

        return network.accuracy


    def create_set(self, network):
        """Set network properties.
        Args:
            network (list): The network parameters
            Used in the mutation process after the first evolution
        """

        self.network = network



    def grade(self, pop):
        """Find average fitness for a population.
        Args:
            pop (list): The population of networks
        Returns:
            (float): The average accuracy of the population
        """
        summed = reduce(add, (self.fitness(network) for network in pop))
        return summed / float((len(pop)))


    def breed(self, mother, father):
        """Make one child as part as their parents.
        Args:
            mother (list): Optimizer() object parameters
            father (lit): Optimizer() object parameters
        Returns:
            (list): One network object as an Optimizer() object
        """



        child = [0,0,0,0]


        # Loop through the parameters and pick params for the kid.

        child[0] = random.choice([mother.input_layer_to_hidden_layer, father.input_layer_to_hidden_layer])

        child[1] = random.choice([mother.hidden_layer_to_output_layer, father.hidden_layer_to_output_layer])

        child[2] = random.choice([mother.b1, father.b1])

        child[3] = random.choice([mother.b2, father.b2])


        #Create a network object and assign child[list] values to it
        network = Optimizer()
        network.create_set(child)
        network.input_layer_to_hidden_layer = child[0]
        network.hidden_layer_to_output_layer = child[1]
        network.b1 = child[2]
        network.b2 = child[3]


        #Mutate
        if self.mutation_rate > random.random():
            network.input_layer_to_hidden_layer = self.mutate(self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer_shape_lines, self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer_shape_columns, network.input_layer_to_hidden_layer)
            network.hidden_layer_to_output_layer = self.mutate(self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer_shape_lines, self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer_shape_columns, network.hidden_layer_to_output_layer)
            network.b1 = self.mutate_biases(self.b1_lines, network.b1)
            network.b2 = self.mutate_biases(self.b2_lines, network.b2)





        return network



    def mutate(self, shape_array_lines, shape_array_columns, weights_array):
        """Two ways of operating mutation on weights.
            Mutate every single weight by multiplying each weight by a random number.
            Mutate an arbitrary random number of weights (e.g., from 1 to 100) by multiplying each mutated weight by a random number.
            The second technique does not seem to work for an undetermined reason"""


        #First technique
        mutation_weights = np.random.random((shape_array_lines, shape_array_columns))

        return mutation_weights*weights_array




    def mutate_biases(self, shape_array_columns, biases_array):
        """Mutate biases using the same technique as the second thechnique used for weights"""



        random_number_mutated_biases = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 100)

        list_random_indices_lines = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = shape_array_columns, size = (random_number_mutated_biases))

        d = 0

        for _ in range(random_number_mutated_biases):

            i = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=+1.1)#random number (with arbitrary values between range)
                                                        #used for multiplying mutated weight

            #Call a particular bias by calling it by its indices, and modify it by adding i
            biases_array[list_random_indices_lines[d]][0] = biases_array[list_random_indices_lines[d]][0] + i

            d +=1

        return biases_array





    def evolve(self, pop):
        """Evolve a population of networks.
        Args:
            pop (list): A list of network parameters
            x: a Differentiatior between first phase before first evolution and second phase after first evolution
        Returns:
            (list): The evolved population of networks
        """


        # Get scores for each network.
        graded = [(network.fitness(network), network) for network in pop]




        for network in pop:
            print("accuracy before =", network.fitness(network))

        # Sort on the scores.
        graded = [x[1] for x in sorted(graded, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=False)]



        # Get the number we want to keep for the next gen.
        retain_length = int(len(graded)*self.retain)

        # The parents are every network we want to keep.
        parents = graded[:retain_length]


        # For those we aren't keeping, randomly keep some anyway.
        for individual in graded[retain_length:]:
            if self.random_select > random.random():
                parents.append(individual)

        # Now find out how many spots we have left to fill.
        parents_length = len(parents)
        desired_length = len(pop) - parents_length
        children = []

        # Add children, which are bred from two remaining networks.
        while len(children) < desired_length:

            # Get a random mom and dad.
            male = random.randint(0, parents_length-1)
            female = random.randint(0, parents_length-1)

            # Assuming they aren't the same network...
            if male != female:
                male = parents[male]
                female = parents[female]

                # Breed them.
                baby = self.breed(male, female)

                # Add the children one at a time.
                if len(children) < desired_length:
                        children.append(baby)



        parents.extend(children)



        total_nbr_values = 0
        for i in pop:
            for j in parents:
                if i == j:
                    total_nbr_values +=1
                    print("same value")

        print("total =", total_nbr_values)


        for network in parents:
            print("accuracy after =", network.fitness(network))




        return parents





    def create_population(self, count, dataset):
        """Create a population of random networks.
        Args:
            count (int): Number of networks to generate, aka the
                size of the population
            dataset (string): dataset used for the experiment
        Returns:
            (list): Population of network objects
        """
        pop = []

        for _ in range(0, count):

            # Create a random network.
            network = Optimizer()
            network.create_neural_network(dataset)
            # Add the network to our population.
            pop.append(network)



        return pop

    def evaluate_neural_network(self):
        """ Get result of the chosen fitness function as an Optimizer() object.
            Accuracy is just a name and does not necessarily mean the actual accuracy."""

        self.accuracy = neural_network_evaluator(self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer,
                            self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer, self.b1, self.b2)

        print(self.accuracy) #Display network cost value.


    def print_network(self):
        """Print out a network and its cost value in the 'log.txt' file."""
        logging.info(self.network)
        logging.info("Network accuracy: %.2f%%" % (self.accuracy))
```

Third module:

```
"""Entry point to evolving the neural network. Start here."""
import logging
from optimizer_Neuroevolution_ameliored import Optimizer
from tqdm import tqdm

# Setup logging.
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filename='log.txt'
)


def train_networks(networks):
    """Train each network.
    Args:
        networks (list): Current population of networks
    """

    pbar = tqdm(total=len(networks))
    for network in networks:
        network.evaluate_neural_network()
        pbar.update(1)
    pbar.close()



def get_average_accuracy(networks):
    """Get the average cost value for a group of networks.
    Args:
        networks (list): List of networks
    Returns:
        float: The average cost value of a population of networks.
    """

    total_accuracy = 0
    for network in networks:
        total_accuracy += network.accuracy

    return total_accuracy / len(networks)



def generate(generations, population, dataset):
    """Generate a network with the genetic algorithm.
    Args:
        generations (int): Number of times to evole the population
        population (int): Number of networks in each generation
        dataset (str): Dataset to use for training/evaluating
    """

    #Create an initial population of random networks
    optimizer = Optimizer()
    networks = optimizer.create_population(population, dataset)

    #Train them
    train_networks(networks)

    #Print out generation number
    logging.info("***Doing generation %d of %d***" %
                     (1, generations))

    print("generation", 1)

        # Get the average cost value for this generation.
    average_accuracy = get_average_accuracy(networks)

        # Print out the average cost value for this generation.
    logging.info("Generation average: %.2f%%" % (average_accuracy))
    logging.info('-'*80)

    # Evolve the first generation.
    networks = optimizer.evolve(networks)
    train_networks(networks)

    #Print out generation number
    logging.info("***Doing generation %d of %d***" %
                     (2, generations))


    # Get the average cost value for this generation.
    average_accuracy = get_average_accuracy(networks)

    # Print out the average cost value for this generation.
    logging.info("Generation average: %.2f%%" % (average_accuracy))
    logging.info('-'*80)


    # Evolve, except on the last iteration.
    for i in range(generations-2):

        print("generation", i+2)

        print("Before evolving process")

        print("values of weights from input layer to hidden layer are:")

        print(networks[0].input_layer_to_hidden_layer[0][0])
        print(networks[0].input_layer_to_hidden_layer[0][2])
        print(networks[0].input_layer_to_hidden_layer[5][2])
        print(networks[0].input_layer_to_hidden_layer[5][8])

        print("values of weights from hidden layer to output layer are:")

        print(networks[0].hidden_layer_to_output_layer[0][0])
        print(networks[0].hidden_layer_to_output_layer[3][6])
        print(networks[0].hidden_layer_to_output_layer[1][56])
        print(networks[0].hidden_layer_to_output_layer[7][23])

        networks = optimizer.evolve(networks)
        #networks = optimizer.create_population(population, networks, x)

        print("After evolving process")

        print("values of weights from input layer to hidden layer are:")

        print(networks[0].input_layer_to_hidden_layer[0][0])
        print(networks[0].input_layer_to_hidden_layer[0][2])
        print(networks[0].input_layer_to_hidden_layer[5][2])
        print(networks[0].input_layer_to_hidden_layer[5][8])

        print("values of weights from hidden layer to output layer are:")

        print(networks[0].hidden_layer_to_output_layer[0][0])
        print(networks[0].hidden_layer_to_output_layer[3][6])
        print(networks[0].hidden_layer_to_output_layer[1][56])
        print(networks[0].hidden_layer_to_output_layer[7][23])





        train_networks(networks)

        print("Novelty accuracy is:")

        for network in networks:
            network.evaluate_neural_network()

        print("Novelty Novelty accuracy is:")

        for network in networks:
            network.evaluate_neural_network()

        #Print out generation number
        logging.info("***Doing generation %d of %d***" %
                     (i + 3, generations))

        # Get the average cost value for generations starting from third generation
        average_accuracy_pop = get_average_accuracy(networks)

        # Print out the average cost value for generations starting from third generation
        logging.info("Generation average: %.2f%%" % (average_accuracy))
        logging.info('-'*80)

    # Sort our final population of networks aka the last generation.
    networks = sorted(networks, key=lambda x: x.accuracy, reverse=False)

    # Print out the top 5 networks of the last generation.
    print_networks(networks[:5])


def print_networks(networks):
    """Print a list of networks.
    Args:
        networks (list): The population of networks
    """

    logging.info('-'*80)
    for network in networks:
        network.print_network()


def main():
    """Evolve a network."""
    generations = 30  # Number of times to evole the population.
    population = 10  # Number of networks in each generation.
    dataset = 'mnist' # Dataset

    # Print out the number of generations and number of individuals chosen
    logging.info("***Evolving %d generations with population %d***" %
                 (generations, population))

    generate(generations, population, dataset)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So I expected the output of the loss values for the same network objects to be the same from a generation to another, but when recalculating the loss value through neural_network_evaluator() function, it displays completly different values.

Actually the loss values of the ten networks from the population from one generation to another should only decrease or remain the same, but they are increasing, which is what I don't understand.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call neural_network_evaluator() from your first module, it uses a new training set generated from get_mnist(), which is drawn randomly.

```
#Shuffle train set to randomize it as it is organized from digits 0 to 9
shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(m)
X_train, Y_train = X_train[:, shuffle_index], Y_train[:, shuffle_index]
```

If you want the evaluation to return the same result each time you call it, you need to evaluate it against the same training set rather than drawing a new one.

(Disclaimer: I haven't heard of using evolutionary algorithms on neural networks, so I can't comment at all on how well this works, or how to select the training sets for it.)

Comment: You're right, but it is not what makes it calculate a different value for the loss value. I tried to remove this random permutation and it still does the same changes in calculation, which I find to be a problem. And with good reason, because when you shuffle this array, it shuffles over the 60 000 different examples, but as the loss value is calculated over these 60 000 different examples, it doesn't change result that it calculates one before another, they are just summed all together in the end, and the mean is calculated. So I still can't find why

Comment: Ah, indeed - I only now noticed that the full X_train set is still used (I read it as a permutation followed by slicing).